# Nginx add cross origin support

Tags: nginx

My application run on local host and i proxy localhost:80 to localhost:1337(my program), how can i fix cross origin error when proxy. I can fix it on server side because i cannot redact a program. It is docker image.

I tried getting SSL certificate. And setting up redirect.

My config:

```
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops my bad Https works only on port 443 by default so you have to add origin on port :443 not :80